# Solr: How can I edit priority search as field in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, search, magento-2.0.2, solr

How can I edit priority search as field in Magento 2? I want search like below:

1. SKU
2. Product name
3. Category
4. Attribute

But I don't where can I edit it? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Define priority in solrconfig.xml of your collection.

```
<requestHandler name="/spell" class="solr.SearchHandler" startup="lazy">
    <lst name="defaults">
        <str name="df">name_s</str>
        <!-- Solr will use suggestions from both the 'default' spellchecker
             and from the 'wordbreak' spellchecker and combine them.
             collations (re-written queries) can include a combination of
             corrections from both spellcheckers -->
        <str name="spellcheck.dictionary">default</str>
        <str name="spellcheck.dictionary">wordbreak</str>
        <str name="spellcheck">on</str>
        <str name="spellcheck.extendedResults">true</str>
        <str name="spellcheck.count">10</str>
        <str name="spellcheck.alternativeTermCount">5</str>
        <str name="spellcheck.maxResultsForSuggest">5</str>
        <str name="spellcheck.collate">true</str>
        <str name="spellcheck.collateExtendedResults">true</str>
        <str name="spellcheck.maxCollationTries">10</str>
        <str name="spellcheck.maxCollations">5</str>
        <str name="fl">name,price,description,colors,image</str>
        <str name="qf">name_suggest^30 name_suggest_ngram^50.0 colors_suggest^15 colors_suggest_ngram^25.0</str>
        <str name="pf">name_suggest_edge^50.0 colors_suggest_edge^25.0</str>
        <str name="group">true</str>
        <str name="group.field">name_s</str>
    </lst>
    <arr name="last-components">
        <str>spellcheck</str>
    </arr>
</requestHandler>
```

The above is for spell check but you can get an idea from it.

```
<str name="fl">name,price,description,colors,image</str>
<str name="qf">name_suggest^30 name_suggest_ngram^50.0 colors_suggest^15 colors_suggest_ngram^25.0</str>
<str name="pf">name_suggest_edge^50.0 colors_suggest_edge^25.0</str>
```